# Why is $BPP^{NP}$ in polynomial hierarchy?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, time-complexity

Why is $BPP^{NP}$ in the polynomial hierarchy?
I know that $BPP$ is contained in $NP^{NP}$, so $BPP$ is inside $PH$. However, how does that imply $BPP^{NP}$ is inside the polynomial hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

$BPP\subset PH$ does NOT imply that $BPP^{NP}\subset PH$. You have to go through the proof of $BPP\subset PH$ and notice that it relativizes, i.e., also holds if the Turing-machines have access to an oracle.

Comment: are you saying that by checking the proof, I am able to see that $BPP^{NP}\in(NP^{NP})^{NP}$ something like that? Thanks! $(NP^{NP})^{NP}$ seems to just be $NP^{NP}$ since the last oracle seems to be redundant?

Comment: These are not really research level questions, so maybe you should rather ask them at https://cs.stackexchange.com/.